# Convert 2d array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How would you convert a 2d array to a vector? This is what I have so far. It compiles, but it only outputs "hey" and then vector subscript out of range error occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr[2][3] = { { "hey", "what", "up" }, { "how", "you", "doin" } };
    vector<vector<string>> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){        //creating row
        vec.push_back(vector<string>());
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++){        //creating columns for the rows
        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){    
            vec[m].push_back("");
        }
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){        //storing and printing data
        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++){
        //  vec[n].push_back(arr[m][n]);
            vec[m][n] = arr[m][n];
            cout << vec[n][m];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: btw there are only 2 rows and 3 columns. first line where you create rows.. should be i<2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistaken rows with columns in cout. The line:

```
cout << vec[n][m];
```

should be:

```
cout << vec[m][n];
```

For the future, you may consider using vector's method [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/). This code will throw an exception which is far more easier to debug.

```
cout << vec.at(n).at(m);
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can do it with one line:

```
// Define and initialize a vector with 2D array
vector<vector<string>> vec = {vector<string>(begin(arr[0]), end(arr[0])),
                              vector<string>(begin(arr[1]), end(arr[1]))};

cout << arr[1][2] << endl;  // cout: "doin"
cout << vec[1][2] << endl;  // cout: "doin"

// print all elements
for (auto row : vec)
    for (auto elem : row)
        cout << elem << " "; // cout: hey what up how you doin
```